# Fortran internal write suddenly an error according to Intel compiler

Tags: io, fortran, intel-fortran

A Fortran code I am working on has several lines similar to

```
WRITE(filename, '(A16,"_",I4,".dat")') filename, indx
```

This code has been successfully compiled and run literally hundreds of times, on many different platforms and pretty much all major compilers.  But suddenly the newest (or, new, anyway) Intel compiler doesn't like it.  It gives a warning message `"forrtl: .... Internal file write-to-self; undefined results"`.  After this line executes, `"filename"`, which was a reasonable character array, becomes blank.

I suppose the problem is that `filename` is both an input into the write and the destination of the internal write.  The fix is easy enough.  It works to replace `filename` as the destination with something like `filename_tmp`.  But as I have said, this has never been necessary until now.

So I am wondering, does filename as both an input and destination violate the Fortran standard, but all these compilers have been turning a blind eye to it for all these years, and now Intel is getting strict?  Or is Intel being "snobbish"?  Or outright buggy?

Comment: Although this output statement isn't allowed, you can do something similar using assignment: `filename=TRIM(filename)//'_'//int2str(indx)//'.dat` (as ugly as that is) instead of using a temporary copy. The key difference is that the assignment statement does evaluate the right-hand side fully before assigning.

Comment: It would be good to add accepted/not-accepted versions of the compilers, to make it more obvious to anyone else wondering whether they have this same issue.

Comment: This doesn't look right at all. Even if this was acceptable by the compiler, Fortran should issue a runtime error (End of record) when you run it, because you try to write to `filename` itself plus 9 more characters. Furthermore, even if you replace the second `filename` with `trim(filename)`, and assuming trimmed `filename` still has 9 characters free, gfortran will issue a runtime error. String concatenation as francescalus suggested is just the most elegant solution.

Comment: @Pap, that write statement doesn't write `filename` plus 9 characters: it writes _the first 16 letters_ (or fewer) of `filename` plus some more. If `character(len=25) filename` then there's no problem.

Comment: @francescalus Correct. but even if `len(filename)>=25` this doesn't look right. As I was reading that write statement, I immediately thought "why not concatenate strings instead?".

Comment: Oh yes, @Pap, it's certainly fragile but programmers who can make crazy assumptions about how their variable look can make equally crazy code.

Comment: @francescalus I am actually surprised this is acceptable by gfortran, although it still issues a runtime error. ifort does a better job in this case.

Comment: @Pap, I think a purely runtime error is fine (and that's what ifort appears to give): one wants runtime checks (there are plenty of cases that can't be caught when compiling) and maybe compile-time checks don't add much? (Ideal would be compile-time where possible and runtime in other cases, but compiler writers may have other priorities.) Complicating this is that the statement is only erroneous if data transfer happens: so not all statements like that should be caught when compiling.

Comment: @francescalus probably fine too, just as using `foo(5,:)` is ok but can cause a runtime warning when the elements extracted from `foo` need to be in continuous memory locations, which is true for `foo(:,5)` but not for `foo(5,:)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Execution<sup>1</sup> of the `write` statement of the question has always been explicitly prohibited.

We currently see (F2018 12.6.4.5.1 p7):

> During the execution of an output statement that specifies an internal file, no part of that internal file shall be referenced, defined, or become undefined as the result of evaluating any output list item.

`filename` is an internal file, and the evaluation of the output list item `filename` is a reference to that internal file.

This is not a programming violation that the compiler is required to detect, so you can view this as a case of improved diagnostic capability/pickiness of the compiler as you desire. No Fortran program is harmed by the change in this behaviour of the compiler.

Fortran 66 didn't have internal files (or character types), of course, and Fortrans 77, 90 and 95 used different words for the same effect (see for example, F90 9.4.4):

> If an internal file has been specified, an input/output list item must not be in the file or associated with the file.

In case it looks like this is more restrictive, from Fortran 2003 the restrictions for input and output statements are stated separately (only output was quoted above, p8 for input).

---

<sup>1</sup> Note the use of *execution*: there's nothing wrong with the statement itself as a statement. It is allowed to exist in source code that isn't reached. Checking this statement when compiling is not a simple matter.